# Appending back in to the DOM after detaching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a typical html structure of

```
<li>
  <div class="holder">
    <img src="imgSrc" class="masterImage" height="200" width="100">
  </div>
</li>
```

The heights differ, its a masonry layout.

What I want to do it detach the image from the DOM when the page scrolls and it goes out iof the viewport, then reattach it when its in the viewport again or for the first time.

Whats happening is that the images are detaching ok but not reattaching

This is the JQuery library code:

```
(function($) {
$.belowthefold = function(element, settings) {
    var fold = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    return fold <= $(element).offset().top - settings.threshold;
};
$.abovethetop = function(element, settings) {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    return top >= $(element).offset().top + $(element).height() - settings.threshold;
};
$.inviewport = function(element, settings) {
    return !$.rightofscreen(element, settings) && !$.leftofscreen(element, settings) && !$.belowthefold(element, settings) && !$.abovethetop(element, settings);
};
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    "below-the-fold": function(a, i, m) {
        return $.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0});
    },
    "above-the-top": function(a, i, m) {
        return $.abovethetop(a, {threshold : 0});
    },
    "in-viewport": function(a, i, m) {
        return $.inviewport(a, {threshold : 0});
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

And this is how I'm calling the above but as I said, they're not reattaching:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function(event) {
$(".masterImage:below-the-fold").each(function() {
  $(this).detach();
});
$(".masterImage:above-the-top").each(function() {
  $(this).detach();
});
$(".masterImage:in-viewport").each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
});
});
```

Any ideas why this is failing? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When detaching you have to actually store a reference to the element, otherwise it's gone

```
var elements = $(".masterImage:below-the-fold").detach();

// stuff

$('body').append(elements);
```

I'll leave figuring out how to combine that with those pseudo selectors up to you.

Another issue is that once an element is detached, it's no longer in the DOM, hence it has no parent, so `$(this).parent()` doesn't do anything.

It seems like it would be ***a lot*** easier to just hide and show the elements instead of removing them from the DOM ?

Comment: It's a performance issue as it uses infinite scroll... when the master outer reaches 20000px or more the browser is impossibly sluggish with all the imges in the DOM

Comment: But if the elements are present in the DOM on first pageload, does it really help to remove them on scroll later on. I wouldn't think so, and would think that lazy-loading is what you really need, not to remove anything that is not in the viewport, as that would in many cases mess up the layout and scrollbar as well.

Comment: I checked the page with and without images and the difference is massive in terms of scrolling and lag. Without the images there's almost no lag whatsoever. As for messing up layout etc, I will hold the images in a div the exact same size as the image so nothing will change

Comment: Oh, okay! The answer still stands, once the images are detached, they are no longer in the DOM, and `$(".masterImage:in-viewport")` won't find them, you have to keep a reference to whatever you detach.